# Adding custom text field to umbraco form setting

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-forms

How to register additional setting field to umbraco form setting screen. Please refer image for a clear idea

[image]

There are so many tutorials/Documentation about adding additional attribute to field type EX: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-forms/developer/extending/adding-a-fieldtype but can not find any documentation about adding custom setting field to umbraco form setting window. I believe some expert can help on this requirement.

Comment: Needs more clarification - give code or link to the setup you're using please.

Comment: This is the requirement. I'm using Umbraco Forms: 10.5.0. Unfortunately all tutorials/doc are about adding custom property to field types but nothing about adding custom setting field to main form setting screen

Comment: Put all useful info in body, not as comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an option, to be honest. You should, however, be able to style your submit button if you use the "Form CSS class" instead and use something like `.my-forms-class input[type=submit] { color: red };` to target the submit button?

Otherwise, you could try and make a feature request here:  https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco.Forms.Issues/issues/